# Drupal 6 Ubercart - cancel/remove payment on order

Tags: ubercart

I have an older Drupal 6 site using Ubercart. We were recently doing some work to the payment gateways and upon the completion of the work we neglected to remove the test payment gateway and there were several orders that were submitted for which no actual payment was ever made.

My question is - is there a way to remove the erroneous payment and set the order back to non-paid? I know I can change the status, but I need to adjust off the amount that was actually paid in this scenario instead of the customer having to go through the whole purchase again. My thought is that they can just log back in and re-complete their order with the test gateway payment having been removed.

Comment: By the way - Paypal standard is what we use for our regular gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob, I'm afraid it may not be possible. In Ubercart, we handled shopping carts as pseudo order objects, tying cart items directly to a session. Once that cart has been checked out, as I recall, there's no way to run through checkout again with it. You may just need to contact the customers to resubmit the order or process their payment some other way (PayPal money request?).

Fwiw, this is why we made the decision in Commerce to manage all shopping carts as full order objects and use the order ID in the checkout URL. Much cleaner to support this type of behavior.

Comment: Thanks Ryan- REALLY appreciate it. I'm trying to get them to move to D7 and Commerce, but that's a battle in itself.